# How to create factory in angular of an existing service

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, service, factory

I am learning `angularjs` and reading articles on service and factory. One example provided on this [ARTICLE](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/angularjs-service-factory-tutorial/) is this [Service Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/viralpatel/84gJX/).

While reading this I am trying to convert the service into factory, this is link to [My Factory Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fph989fk/). But still it's not working as expected am not sure what I am doing wrong.

**HTML**

```
  <div ng-app="app">
      <div ng-controller="CalculatorController">
          Enter a number:
          <input type="number" ng-model="number" />
          <button ng-click="doSquare()">X<sup>2</sup></button>
          <button ng-click="doCube()">X<sup>3</sup></button>

          <div>Answer: {{answer}}</div>
      </div>
  </div>
```

**JS**

```
    var app = angular.module('app', []);

    app.factory('MathService', function() {
    var myFactory = {};
        myFactory.add = function(a, b) { return a + b };

        myFactory.subtract = function(a, b) { return a - b };

        myFactory.multiply = function(a, b) { return a * b };

        myFactory.divide = function(a, b) { return a / b };

        retutn myFactory;
    });

    app.factory('CalculatorService', function(MathService){
        var calcFactory = {};
        calcFactory.square = function(a) { return MathService.multiply(a,a); };
        calcFactory.cube = function(a) { return MathService.myFactory.multiply(a, MathService.myFactory.multiply(a,a)); };

        return calcFactory;

    });

    app.controller('CalculatorController', function($scope, CalculatorService) {

        $scope.doSquare = function() {
            $scope.answer = CalculatorService.calcFactory.square($scope.number);
        }

        $scope.doCube = function() {
            $scope.answer = CalculatorService.calcFactory.cube($scope.number);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some reason you fiddle complain that it can't instantiate the 'app' module, so everything fails.

anyway, here is a fiddle to a working example: https://jsfiddle.net/gom2q6bz/1/.

Please note that you don't need to call `CalculatorService.calcFactory.cube` but rather `CalculatorService.cube`;

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.factory('MathService', function() {
  var service = {};
  service.add = function(a, b) {
    return a + b
  };

  service.subtract = function(a, b) {
    return a - b
  };

  service.multiply = function(a, b) {
    return a * b
  };

  service.divide = function(a, b) {
    return a / b
  };

  return service;
});

app.factory('CalculatorService', function(MathService) {
  var service = {};
  service.square = function(a) {
    return MathService.multiply(a, a);
  };
  service.cube = function(a) {
    return MathService.multiply(a, MathService.multiply(a, a));
  };

  return service;

});

app.controller('CalculatorController', function($scope, CalculatorService) {

  $scope.doSquare = function() {
    $scope.answer = CalculatorService.square($scope.number);
  }

  $scope.doCube = function() {
    $scope.answer = CalculatorService.cube($scope.number);
  }
});
```